# Connecting to IP#1 automatically redirects to IP#2

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, apache2

I have setup Ubuntu Server 14.04 on a independent server, with its internal IP `10.10.10.9`.
This is supposed to be a closed(as in, should only be accessible by other `10.10.10.X` IPs only), and works fine as is, but now I'm told to open this server to the world.

I have set the network router to redirect `121.66.XXX.XXX:XXXX` to `10.10.10.9`.

The problem is this:

When I connect to `121.66.XXX.XXX:XXXX`, the Web-Browser address automatically changes to `10.10.10.9`, which it shouldn't do. The contents on `10.10.10.9` IP cannot be seen from other networks, unless connecting `121.66.XXX.XXX:XXXX`.

I've looked at the apache2 `access.log` and saw the following output:

```
121.66.XXX.XXX - - [07/Jan/2015:15:00:45 +0900] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 496 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36"
```

and can only imagine that this is telling me that it's being redirected.

I've tried searching anything that may help, and still clueless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apache log seems to suggest that the redirect is done at application level.

Some applications have a `siteurl` option configured at install time, and if you visit the application from another URL, they redirect you to the *siteurl*.
So, have a look at your application configurations and eventually change that option to match the external IP.